# Angular ngFor duplicates first value when I add to the front of the list

Tags: angular

I have a simple list I iterate through with ngFor. The ngFor is inside a form element so I have to use the name attribute with ngModel to display values. My problem comes when I add to the front of the list, the new element gets added but also changes the previous first elements value (only the value in the DOM) to the newly added value.

[Here's the link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dwc5ve?file=src/app/app.component.html) to an example of what's going on.

Anyone know why the old first element gets changed in the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know how avoid: using trackby

```
<div *ngFor="let testUnit of testList; let i = index;trackBy:trackBy">
...
</div>
```

And in .ts

```
  trackBy(index,obj)
  {
    return index
  }
```

But the reason is relation about `ngModel` and the need of give
`name`. But really I don't know the mechanism :(

**Update** There're another way that is that the "name" don't relation with the "i"

If we imagine that our array is like

```
  testList = [
    { index:0,value: 'placeholder 1' },
    { index:1,value: 'placeholder 2' },
    { index:2,value: 'placeholder 3' },
  ];
```

And the "add" like

```
add() {
    this.testList.unshift({ index:this.testList.length,
                            value: 'new value' });
  }
```

We can use

```
<div *ngFor="let testUnit of testList; let i = index;">
  <input
    class="test-input"
    [name]="'name'+testUnit.index"
    [(ngModel)]="testUnit.value"
  />
</div>
```